# not able to create sails project getting error sails command not found

Tags: sails.js

Getting error:

> No command 'sails' found, did you mean:  Command 'rails' from package 'ruby-railties' (universe)  Command 'sail' from package 'bsdgames' (universe) sails: command not found

Version detail:

- npm -v : 3.10.5
- node -v : 6.3.1
- OS : ubuntu

Comment: When are you getting this error? Show code!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . At a minimum, we need to see your code and know what line threw the error message.

Comment: try `sudo npm install -g sails`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your sails package is not installed.
Try running

```
sudo npm install -g sails
```

Answer (score 0):

First hit `sudo npm -g install sails`

If you see the same error again, find the `bin/sails` file in your system.

For me it was `/home/$USER/.npm-global/bin/sails`.

Then create an alias `$ alias sails='/home/$USER/.npm-global/bin/sails`.

Then `sails --version`. You should see the output of your version.